# How to create emty linked list in C?

Tags: c, list

I instalize list and how to make list emty?

```
struct node {
   int data;
  struct node *next;
}
```

Comment: More code. Depends on the implementation and the API. You show us a **node**, not a **list**, so we have no idea what an empty list **might** look like.

Answer (score 1):

An empty list has no nodes in it:

```
struct node *list = NULL;
```

If you want to add nodes to the end of the list:

```
void addNode(struct node **list, int value)
{
    struct node *newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (newnode == NULL) {
        perror("malloc failed");
        exit(1);
    } 
    newnode->data = value;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    if (*list == NULL) {
        *list = newnode;
    } else {
        struct node *temp = *list;
        while (temp->next != NULL) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = newnode;
    }
}

....

addNode(&list, 1);
addNode(&list, 2);
addNode(&list, 3);
```